# Graphql trying to create an object of get_user_model : __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'

Tags: django, python-3.x, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I've recently started learning GraphQL. I created a Mutation for a custom-defined model and it's working fine. But when I try to do the same for the Django built-in user model. I'm getting an error. Not able to resolve it.
I'm trying to create a new user by creating an object of get_user_model through GraphQL.

```
class CreateUser(graphene.Mutation):
user = graphene.Field(UserType)

class Arguments:
    username = graphene.String(required=True)
    password = graphene.String(required=True)
    email = graphene.String(request=True)

def mutate(self,info,username,password,email):
    user = get_user_model(username=username,email=email)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return CreateUser(user=user)

class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_user = CreateUser.Field()
```

Getting the above error. Not sure what's the problem. Please anyone explain.

Traceback error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql/

Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.6.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'graphene_django',
 'links']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sunilhn/Documents/programming/Envs/graphenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/sunilhn/Documents/programming/Envs/graphenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/sunilhn/Documents/programming/Envs/graphenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/sunilhn/Documents/programming/Envs/graphenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sunilhn/Documents/programming/Envs/graphenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 62, in view
    self = cls(**initkwargs)
  File "/Users/sunilhn/Documents/programming/Envs/graphenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/graphene_django/views.py", line 79, in __init__
    schema = graphene_settings.SCHEMA
  File "/Users/sunilhn/Documents/programming/Envs/graphenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/graphene_django/settings.py", line 117, in __getattr__
    val = perform_import(val, attr)
  File "/Users/sunilhn/Documents/programming/Envs/graphenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/graphene_django/settings.py", line 56, in perform_import
    return import_from_string(val, setting_name)
  File "/Users/sunilhn/Documents/programming/Envs/graphenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/graphene_django/settings.py", line 70, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/Users/sunilhn/Documents/programming/Envs/graphenv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
    <source code not available>
  File "/Users/sunilhn/Documents/programming/django_fs/myDjangoProjects/graphqlhackernews/graphqlhackernews/schema.py", line 3, in <module>
    import users.schema
  File "/Users/sunilhn/Documents/programming/django_fs/myDjangoProjects/graphqlhackernews/users/schema.py", line 29, in <module>
    class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
  File "/Users/sunilhn/Documents/programming/django_fs/myDjangoProjects/graphqlhackernews/users/schema.py", line 30, in Mutation
    create_user = CreateUser.Field()
  File "/Users/sunilhn/Documents/programming/Envs/graphenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/graphene/types/mutation.py", line 146, in Field
    required=required,
  File "/Users/sunilhn/Documents/programming/Envs/graphenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/graphene/types/field.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.args = to_arguments(args or OrderedDict(), extra_args)
  File "/Users/sunilhn/Documents/programming/Envs/graphenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/graphene/types/argument.py", line 94, in to_arguments
    arg = Argument.mounted(arg)
  File "/Users/sunilhn/Documents/programming/Envs/graphenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/graphene/types/mountedtype.py", line 19, in mounted
    **unmounted.kwargs

Exception Type: TypeError at /graphql/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'
```

Comment: Hello Sunil I saw you are creating a "create user" mutation, you could try using the [django-graphql-auth](https://github.com/PedroBern/django-graphql-auth). It does  provide user registration with graphql, along with more features.

Comment: @pedrobern Thanks for the info. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue. There was typo in defining the email argument, instead of requirement it was typed as request. It's working now.